# Linking a field to a node and recording meter readings

Tags: views, 7, datetime, entities

I am trying to achieve the following :-

1. I have a custom content type called as Energy Meter Record that has the following fields:-
   a. A field collection called as Meter Record Sheet that has the following fields in it

   [image]

   After Couple of entries the content looks like this localhost/ogdev/node/17

   [image]

   2. Now what i want is that when a user clicks on the meter say METER XYZ1 it gets    directed to a page that records the entry for that meter(XYZ1) and for this i have made a new content type called as Meter Log that looks like this after a couple of entries though it is manually created by me and looks like this localhost/ogdev/node/18

      [image]

**Now i want to link the MeterXYZ1 to a LOG where user can enter the details. How to do that so that is get prepopulated and refers to the meter? Any suggestions , am i doing it wrong and how to achieve this please guide.**

Thanks :)

Comment: I think the question needs a bit more clarity. Did not get the question properly.

Comment: Hi @MohammedShameem , i just want to direct the user which has the meters added to his account and let him enter the meter readings. First step was to let the user enter meter details which 1st snapshot has, then he has all his meters added under his account and now i want when the user clicks meter XYZ1 then i want to let him add the meter readings for a month or days etc....basically how to link these things?